# Customise google map annotations

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, annotations

How can I customise google map like this? I have to add custom icons as annotations. Clicking the annotations should show a small pop up box like this.Please help me.[image]

Comment: What problems are you having? [Custom Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons) - [Custom InfoWindows](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) ([example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html))

Comment: I'm newbie . dont know how to start

Comment: Start with the documentation, look at the examples, copy them and change them.  Make your custom markers with standard InfoWindows.  Once you have that working customize the InfoWindows.

Comment: great . Those examples has source too. thanks. Juts post ur comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the documentation ([Custom Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons) - [Custom InfoWindows](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html) ([example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html))), look at the examples, copy them and change them. Make your custom markers with standard InfoWindows. Once you have that working customize the InfoWindows.